# Why can't I login to an imap server twice in Python

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

As the error message below states, I cannot log in because I'm in state LOGOUT and not in state NONAUTH. How do I get from LOGOUT to NONAUTH?

Example below (obviously the login credentials are faked below)

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import imaplib
>>> imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com",993)
>>> imap_server.login('something@myserver.com', 'mypassword')
('OK', ['something@myserver.com Joe Smith authenticated (Success)'])
>>> imap_server.logout()
('BYE', ['LOGOUT Requested'])
>>> imap_server.login('something@myserver.com', 'mypassword')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 505, in login
    typ, dat = self._simple_command('LOGIN', user, self._quote(password))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1070, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 825, in _command
    ', '.join(Commands[name])))
imaplib.error: command LOGIN illegal in state LOGOUT, only allowed in states NONAUTH
>>> quit()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're trying to do is illegal in IMAP. If you read over [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501), it explicitly defines [Logout State](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-3.4) as a state from which there is no return. Whether you get an error from `imaplib` itself, or from the server, or you get really unlucky and it works and takes you into undefined-behavior territory… the answer is the same: don't do it.

So, you have to create a new connection to the server to login again:

```
>>> imap_server.logout()
('BYE', ['LOGOUT Requested'])
>>> imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com",993)
>>> imap_server.login('something@myserver.com', 'mypassword')
('OK', ['something@myserver.com Joe Smith authenticated (Success)'])
```

(Of course you don't have to rebind the same name `imap_server` to the new connection.)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly it!

Comment: While you explained that LOGOUT state is a state from which there is no return, you didn't exactly explain how the OP go into a state of NONAUTH - is that the state you are in when make an IMAP connection? That is, after this `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com",993)`? But you cannot get to NONAUTH state from any other state? I don't see any reference in RFC3501.

Comment: @Devy: I didn't explain the entire state machine from RFC 3501 because RFC 3501 already explains it pretty well. Section 3 says, "The initial state is identified in the server greeting." Section 3.1 says, "Not Authenticated State … is entered when a connection starts unless the connection has been pre-authenticated." Otherwise, "Authenticated State … is entered when a pre-authenticated connection starts". After 3.4 there's an ASCII-ART diagram that shows all the ways to get to each state. There is no way to get back to Not Authenticated if you leave it.