# want to monitor new mails with different account imap credential

Tags: node.js, imap

I'm implementing an Email Client Application to monitor new email arrival for different IMAP configuration simultaneously. I preferred Nodejs, but I stuck up with connection creation.

Let me explain with following example:

I have 3 IMAP configurations (it's not restricted to 3, each provider may have 10, 100, 1000 or > 1000 users).

1. Gmail
2. Yahoo!
3. Hotmail.

I did the configuration for these 3 providers. Now I want to monitor above 3 mail servers for different users. Let's say Gmail with 1000 different users, Yahoo! with other 1000 users and Hotmail with 1000 users.

My question is I want to monitor new email arrival for every user with every mailbox.

Will NodeJS be helpful to do this? It's going to create many TCP connections.

I want to implement this with less network cost.

Comment: Make a queue, let's say 1000 connections at a time, check for mails, first in first out.

Comment: Did you manage to handle so many accounts? In terms of performance and CPU usage not any problem?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to this question:

[Why can't I login to an imap server twice in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112695/why-cant-i-login-to-an-imap-server-twice-in-python)

What you are expecting IMAP to do cannot be done. When you connect to
an IMAP server you issue a LOGIN, do some stuff, then eventually give
a LOGOUT. After the LOGOUT you cannot do another LOGIN.

So whatever IMAP library you use will have to generate a TCP socket
connection for each mailbox you check. With that said Node.js has
some pretty easy-to-use IMAP modules:

- https://github.com/andris9/inbox - Easy checking of inboxes
- https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap - More low-level IMAP stuff